# How to install Nokogiri using Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, nokogiri, chef-solo

I have chef-solo version 12.6

In my recipe I have this code:

```
ruby_block "Parse the XML File " do
    block do
        require 'nokogiri'
    end
end
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- nokogiri
```

I used the omnibus chef installer and I cannot upgrade to the latest chef-solo.

How do I get Nokogiri to load?

Comment: add a `chef_gem 'nokogiri'` resource before your ruby_block, so the nokogiri gem will be available to require.

Comment: "is there anything I can do to parse my xml file?" The correct question at this point is, "How do I install Nokogiri?". Once you're past that then parsing the XML is the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we didn't start including Nokogiri in the installers until Chef 12.7.

Comment: Then is there any other way to do the parsing of xml without adding additional gems?  I am afraid that I cannot load anything in my environment due to some constraint.

Comment: REXML is included with Ruby.